# Remove multiple specific childNodes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, removechild, nodelist

I just wonder on how to remove specific html elements inside div.

Using JavaScript, I research already removing child but I found only removed one element with the array order like [0] and removed all child.
My problem is how to remove the specific html multiple tags element.

**Need to remove all `<Ul>` elements inside `#custom_description_video` div**

Here is the sample image:

[image]

Comment: Do you need to remove all `<ul>` elements that are direct children of the `#custom_description_video` element?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: `for (const ul of document.querySelectorAll('#cutom_description_video ul')) ul.remove()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Element.remove() in a loop

```js
const uls = document.querySelectorAll('#custom_description_video > ul')

uls.forEach(el => el.remove())
```

```html
<div id="custom_description_video">
  <div>Some div</div>
  <div>Another div</div>
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Very helpful for me, and I'm pretty sure to the others in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach to remove all child tag elements:

```
var parentElement = document.getElementById('custom_description_video');


Array.prototype.slice.call(parentElement.getElementsByTagName('ul')).forEach(function(item) { item.parentNode.removeChild(item); } );
```